# Some questions about llncs2e class

Tags: formatting, lncs

First, I want to say, I need someone who knows about the `llncs2e` class of the springer.

I am preparing a paper with `llncs2e` class. the explanations are as follows:

http://www.springer.com/computer/lncs/lncs+authors?SGWID=0-40209-0-0-0

Let me tell you first, what I have done so far:

- I downloaded the `llncs2e.zip`
- Then I downloaded the `typeinst.zip`
- Copied `typeinst.tex` into the `llncs2e` directory (I hope it was the right thing)
- I typed my paper into the `typeinst.tex`
- And right now, **I have finished** my paper.

**1) However,** in the instructions section, they say

> We want to add hyperlinks to your manuscript in the online version, so we recommend the use of LaTeX2e for the preparation of your camera-ready manuscript, together with the corresponding Springer class file.

Here, what is a **manuscript** and what do they meaning with **hyperlink**?

**2) There** is a file named `svmono.zip`. They say it is for our **monographs**. Do I have to use it in a way? and what is a **monograph**?

**3) In the** `typeinst.pdf` (also example paper), they say

> Please use the commands `\label` and `\ref` for cross-references and the commands `\bibitem` and `\cite` for references to the bibliography, to enable us to
>   create hyperlinks at these places

Again. what is this hyperlink thing in a pdf file?

**4) In their** example tex file, they suggest to use **bibtex** as follows:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{4}

\bibitem{jour} Smith, T.F., Waterman, M.S.: Identification of Common Molecular
Subsequences. J. Mol. Biol. 147, 195--197 (1981)

\bibitem{lncschap} May, P., Ehrlich, H.C., Steinke, T.: ZIB Structure Prediction Pipeline:
Composing a Complex Biological Workflow through Web Services. In: Nagel,
W.E., Walter, W.V., Lehner, W. (eds.) Euro-Par 2006. LNCS, vol. 4128,
pp. 1148--1158. Springer, Heidelberg (2006)

\bibitem{book} Foster, I., Kesselman, C.: The Grid: Blueprint for a New Computing
Infrastructure. Morgan Kaufmann, San Francisco (1999)

\bibitem{proceeding1} Czajkowski, K., Fitzgerald, S., Foster, I., Kesselman, C.: Grid
Information Services for Distributed Resource Sharing. In: 10th IEEE
International Symposium on High Performance Distributed Computing, pp.
181--184. IEEE Press, New York (2001)

\bibitem{proceeding2} Foster, I., Kesselman, C., Nick, J., Tuecke, S.: The Physiology of the
Grid: an Open Grid Services Architecture for Distributed Systems
Integration. Technical report, Global Grid Forum (2002)

\bibitem{url} National Center for Biotechnology Information, \url{http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov}

\end{thebibliography}
```

However, I have created my own `typeinst.bib` file and simple added these line end of the my tex file:

```
\bibliography{typeinst}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

And it works with the `\cite{}` command, but I am wondering if there is relation between the format they suggest and the this hyperlink thing? I wonder if they are meaning to create a hyperlink for clicking a citation like `[4]` ? And am I allowed to use bibtex like I did?

**5) To type** pseudo-codes in our paper, they say;

```
\subsection{Program Code}

Program listings or program commands in the text are normally set in
typewriter font, e.g., CMTT10 or Courier.

\medskip

\noindent
{\it Example of a Computer Program}
\begin{verbatim}
program Inflation (Output)
  {Assuming annual inflation rates of 7%, 8%, and 10%,...
   years};
   const
     MaxYears = 10;
   var
     Year: 0..MaxYears;
     Factor1, Factor2, Factor3: Real;
   begin
     Year := 0;
     Factor1 := 1.0; Factor2 := 1.0; Factor3 := 1.0;
     WriteLn('Year  7% 8% 10%'); WriteLn;
     repeat
       Year := Year + 1;
       Factor1 := Factor1 * 1.07;
       Factor2 := Factor2 * 1.08;
       Factor3 := Factor3 * 1.10;
       WriteLn(Year:5,Factor1:7:3,Factor2:7:3,Factor3:7:3)
     until Year = MaxYears
end.
\end{verbatim}
%
\noindent
```

Here, do I have to use verbatim only or I can use the *italic* format? **See:** `{\it Example of a Computer Program}`.

And do I have to create my pseudo-code in pascal language? I am asking this just to be sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: some of your questions are about vocabulary.  i can answer a few.  a "monograph" is a book-length document on a single subject; you say you have written a paper, so `svmono` is not for you.  `\label` and `\ref`, `\bibitem` and `\cite` are paired commands that allow a designated item to be linked elsewhere in a text, so that someone looking at the text on-line can click on a reference and be taken there directly.  these should be described in any elementary latex reference, but you seem to be using them correctly if `\cite` works.

Comment: @barbarabeeton thanks for answer. Yes, I said `\cite` command is working but it doesn't create any hyperlink to the source paper. It just assign a reference number like `[4]`. But still, I can't click on it.

Comment: when you view your pdf output on screen, is the "[4]" colored"?  this requires that `\usepackage{hyperref}` appear in your preamble, usually the last package loaded.  to test this, we'd need a compilable example; inventing one without knowing what you already have doesn't give very good answers.  see this question for some hints: [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)